# Batch_update primary key joining table

Tags: codeigniter

i'm having a problem with batch update function with codeigniter, i'm using a joining table for my products and categories, as I have a many to many relationship. I have searched high and low for an answer but still nothing so i have come here to ask more senior technicians for help.

I have 2 columns in a table "product_category" with "product_id" & "category_id" so I can link 1 product to many categories. I have managed to perform the insert query which inserts all the id's fine, but the update is not working. Here's my code:

model:

```
function update_product_cat($product, $cat_id) {            
                 $data = array();
                    foreach( $product as $index => $value )
                        {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'product_id'    => $value ,
                        'category_id'  => $cat_id[ $index ]
                        );
                            }

                    $this->db->update_batch('product_category', $data, 
'product_id');


                                }
```

array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 327 [category_id] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 327 [category_id] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 327 [category_id] => 7 ))
```

My error code:

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '327-3' for key 'PRIMARY'

    `UPDATE product_category SET category_id = CASE WHEN product_id = '327' THEN '3' WHEN product_id = '327' THEN '5' WHEN product_id = '327' THEN '7' ELSE category_id END WHERE product_id IN ('327','327','327')`

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

thanks

Comment: Please, invest some time in formatting your code. If you ask for help, make people want to help and make it easy for them.

Comment: I did try, it was my first time using your wysiwyg and to be honest it was a pain, sorry but my code is highlighted isn't it?

Comment: It's called markdown, not wysiwyg, I'm talking more about line breaks and other things, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Well apologies, it is my fist time, will take greater care next time thanks for the heads up...

Comment: Anyway could you point me in the right direction with my question please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is your entire problem, but it looks like the product_category table has product_id set as a primary key - where it looks like you are trying to enter many identical product_id's.  If that were the case you should probably just be using a regular update not batch, not to mention removing/replacing the primary key.